# What does this mean "Error connecting to SMTP server: (421, b'Service not available')"

Tags: python, html, flask, smtp

I am working on a project where i have to use python to make a form functional so that once you fill the form and submit it, it sends that info to a mail
But it is not working even though it was working before and that is where i got this error from "Error connecting to SMTP server: (421, b'Service not available')"

I have tried everything, i linked my python to a css and html file as the anchors for the frontend, when i submit it is supposed to lead you to a particular page, but it doesn't it just gives me that error

Answer (score 0):

SMTP error 421 denotes a problem with your outgoing server connection. This can often occur as a result of too many connections or a high volume of messages being sent within a short timeframe.
https://www.ongage.com/glossary/smtp-error-421/